# Laravel relationships - accessing related value in view

Tags: laravel, table-relationships

I can't find a solution to a seemingly simple problem with passing related data to a view. I have a model 'Companies' that belongs to 'Regions'.
I've created the `belongsTo` relationship in my Companies model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
protected $table = 'companies';
protected $primaryKey = 'Comp_id';
protected $fillable = ['industrylink_id', 'region_id','companyname','contactno','regno','vatno','salaryroll','numemployees'];

public function employees(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Employee');
}

public function region(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region');
```

Also the `hasMany` relation in the Region model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Region extends Model
{
protected $table = 'regions';

public function companies(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Company');
}    
}
```

My `show` Controller passes the variable for the session row successfully to the view, but the moment I want to access the related table data with the following... (table 'region' with column 'region')

```
<p>Region: {{ $company->region->region }}</p> -->
```

...I get the error

> "Trying to get property of non-object: (View:..."

I've changed my models location to app\Models and I've made all the necessary namespace changes in the models & controllers, as well as the autoload in composer.json. I did a composer dump & config:clear and all of the other mvc references work.

I did not create migrations for the related tables since the tables exist and have standard reference data in it. I assume the relation created in the model is sufficient?

I'd appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Have you ensured that the existing table foreign keys are declared in your Laravel Model relationship methods? I see in your `Company` model that you declared a `$primaryKey`. What's the foreign key that references a `region` in your `companies` table? Declare it in the 2nd parameter of the `belongsTo` method. Example: `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region', 'unusual_region_id')`;

Comment: No, I kept it simple with the Regions table - it's just `id`

Comment: But what is its reference field in the `companies` table?

Comment: It's Region_id (with a capital R). Maybe we're onto something here. I suspect that the Laravel convention works with all lower case letters. I'll  specify it as you suggested and revert.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much @Sandy. Can you post your response as an answer so that I can accept it? I'm new here - don't know if I can accept your comment as answer.

Comment: I'm glad to help. I posted an answer, @PDevH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ensured that the existing table foreign keys are declared in your Laravel Model relationship methods? I see in your `Company` model that you declared a `$primaryKey`. What's the foreign key that references a `Region` in your `companies` table? Declare it in the 2nd parameter of the `belongsTo` method. Example: `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region', 'unusual_region_id');`

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you get this error when variable or relationship is empty, so make sure company is not empty and it has a region. If you're sure company is not empty, just check the relationship:

```
{{ empty($company->region) ? 'No region' : $company->region->region }}
```

Comment: Nope, I have data in both tables. Echo'd your code in controller and it returns `No region`. I'm stumped.

Comment: @PDevH this means some companies do not have region.

Comment: No, can't be that. I have several companies in the table and ALL of them have an unsigned integer value in the `region_id` column, linking to distinct regions.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to :

```
dd($company->region)
```

and see what data it return.

Comment: Yes, echo'd it from controller and it returns `null`. Can't think why.